# Mobile phone validator

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a problem with regex, I want to create pattern which will be check mobile number.

Mobile number starts with /^(50|51|53|57|60|66|69|72|73|78|79|88)/ and has only 9 digits.

Could You help me?

Comment: So any of those 2 digits and 7 more?

Comment: Exacly,  any of those 2 digits and 7 more

Comment: `/^(5[0137]|6[069]|7[2389]|88)[0-9]{7}$/` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex like following

```
$isMobileNumber = preg_match('/^(50|51|53|57|60|66|69|72|73|78|79|88)\d{7}/', $number);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex for that:

```
(?:5[01357]|6[069]|7[2389]|88)\d{7}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4ZHOJxjLBXMYnGNr)